# Invalid Email or Phone Number when creating a new app in the Facebook developer console

Tags: facebook

When I try to create a new app in the [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/), it shows me a popup saying: ***Invalid Email or Phone Number.*** *Please enter a valid email address or mobile number.*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same popup, but when i navigated to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ i found it. So if you check probably that would be there.

Comment: Yeah, the app is there! But when you click on it, its content doesn't show like it used to show when created normally.